# Count separate row on same id from different table : MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I want to count the number of aircon and client under the same `usr_id`. Here's my resources:

clients_db

```
+---------+--------+
| clnt_id | usr_id |
+---------+--------+
|    1    |   a1   |
+---------+--------+
|    2    |   a1   |
+---------+--------+
|    3    |   a2   |
+---------+--------+
|    4    |   a1   |
+---------+--------+
```

aircon_client_db

```
+---------+--------+---------+
|  ac_id  | usr_id | clnt_id |
+---------+--------+---------+
|    1    |   a1   |    1    |
+---------+--------+---------+
|    2    |   a2   |    2    |
+---------+--------+---------+
|    3    |   a2   |    1    |
+---------+--------+---------+
|    4    |   a2   |    3    |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

According to the tables above. I want to count

1. how many `clnt_id` under the same `usr_id`
2. how many `ac_id` under the same `usr_id`

So I coded:

```
select count(acdb.ac_id) as nAC,
count(clnt.clnt_id) as nClnt 
from aircon_client_db acdb 
left join clients_db clnt on clnt.usr_sid=acdb.usr_sid 
where acdb.usr_sid='a1'
```

I expect the answer as following:

1. 3
2. 1

But as I tested. My results are the same for both count - 4. Where did I wrong?

Comment: Your tables do not appear to be normalized.  Please explain what each table is supposed to be doing here.

Comment: 'mechanic id' - i see no such column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen usr_id=mechanic logged in, client_db=mechanic's clients, aircon_client_db=client's aircon detail

Comment: 'Where did I wrong?' - If you are analysing by user_id I would expect to see user_id in the select and a group by user_id. But I think the you conception is flawed and the query should be driven by whatever table holds the user details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count:
 
`clnt_id`s from the table `clients_db` and 
`ac_id`s from the table `aircon_client_db` 
for `usr_sid='a1'`, right?
I don't see the necessity  of joining the tables. 
You can count separately with 2 subqueries in the same query:

```
select 
  (select count(ac_id) from aircon_client_db where usr_sid = 'a1') as nAC,
  (select count(clnt_id) from clients_db where usr_sid = 'a1') as nClnt
```

If there is a case of duplicate `clnt_id`s in `clients_db` or duplicate `ac_id`s in `aircon_client_db`, then use:
`count(distinct clnt_id)` and `count(distinct ac_id)`